# Could not find Chrome (ver. 115.0.5790.170) during PDF creation in Node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

Trying to create a PDF using `puppeteer` & `@jikji/generator` npm libraries in node.js (ver 16.15.1)

It works locally and on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS aws it crashes. Installed necessary dependencies.

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
sudo apt install libx11-xcb1 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxi6 libxtst6 libnss3 libcups2 libxss1 libxrandr2 libasound2 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev
```

Chromium Version

```
chromium-browser --version
Chromium 117.0.5938.149 snap
```

Below is the Error

```
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 115.0.5790.170). This can occur if either
0|npm      |  1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
0|npm      |  2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /root/.cache/puppeteer).
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't install chromium manually, as it will install the latest compatible version itself. Documentation says `"Note: When you install Puppeteer, it downloads a recent version of Chromium (~170MB Mac, ~282MB Linux, ~280MB Win) that is guaranteed to work with the API."`. You can also force it to use the browser you've installed by `executablePath` option on `launch()`.